# Dojo tree - delay until server returns data

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I have a server function that generates JSON representing part of the file system.

The server function is called once the user has selected an item from a pull-down list.

So far so good.

My question is how do I display the tree ONLY when the JSON data has been returned from the server?  Please make your answer as verbose and complete as possible as I'm not a javascript pro by any means!

Answer (score 1):

`var serverFunctionComplete = false;

var x = serverFunction();

while(!serverFunctionComplete) {

//just waiting

}

setTimeout(function() {

serverFunctionComplete = true;//if the server doesn't respond

}, 5000);`

This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You could make ajax request synchronous using the `sync : true` property in the xhr object. This stops other code from executing until the response is recieved from the server and the callback is done executing.

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr"], function(xhr){
  xhr("example.json", {
    handleAs: "json",
    sync: true
  }).then(function(data){
    // Do something with the handled data
  }, function(err){
    // Handle the error condition
  }, function(evt){
    // Handle a progress event from the request if the
    // browser supports XHR2
  });
});
```

However, this is typically not the best practice as asynchronous loading as one of the great things about javascript and ajax. It would be reccomended to do display your tree in the callback function in the xhr so your script does not get hung up polling for a response.

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr"], function(xhr){
  xhr("example.json", {
    handleAs: "json"
  }).then(function(data){
    // Display your Tree!
  }, function(err){
    // Handle the error condition
  });
});
```

For general asynchronous thread management, refer to [Dojo's Deffered class.](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/Deferred.html#dojo-deferred)